# Why does an empty string get enclosed within a single quotes in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've written a simple shell script "sample.sh" as below

```
#!/bin/bash

PARAM1="Parameter1"
PARAM2=\"\"

echo "param1-->[$PARAM1] - param2-->[$PARAM2]"

# sample is a compiled binary that just prints it's command line arugments.
./sample -param1 $PARAM1 -param2 $PARAM2
```

The script is run with -x option as

```
bash -x sample.sh
```

The output which I got is

```
[tspot@raspberrypi : ~/src/sample]$ bash -x sample.sh
+ PARAM1=Parameter1
+ PARAM2='""'
+ echo 'param1-->[Parameter1] - param2-->[""]'
param1-->[Parameter1] - param2-->[""]
+ ./sample -param1 Parameter1 -param2 '""'
arg[0] - [./sample]
arg[1] - [Parameter1]
arg[2] - [""]
[tspot@raspberrypi : ~/src/sample]$
```

My doubt is why do we get a single quote surrounding the empty string in -param2 in the below line

```
+ ./sample -param1 Parameter1 -param2 '""'
```

I would need the line to be

```
+ ./sample -param1 Parameter1 -param2 ""
```

Thanks in Advance. Someone please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

That's just the way bash -x formats things in it's debug output. It's adding the extra ' ' to indicate that the string is literally "" and not an empty string. If you look a few lines below, you can see that ./sample does have the expected output: `arg[2] - [""]`.

Comment: Yes!!! I understood, but I've another binary which fails to execute 


`./binary -param1 $PARAM1 -param2 $PARAM2`


this binary expects `""` in -param2, but since we get `'""'`, it fails.

Comment: @tSpot I don't think you understood. You don't get `'""'`. That's only how it's formatted in the debug output. The actual parameter passed to the binary is `""`. If your binary fails then it's for a different reason.

Comment: Yes!!! I didn't mean to say the shell script fails.

The binary is written in such a way to accept only empty string `""` but not `'""'`. Any possible ways to pass it as expected???

Comment: @tSpot BTW. If the objective is to pass an empty string as an argument to the binary then this isn't the way to do it. This will pass the string `""`, which is not empty.

Comment: @tSpot It is being passed the string `""`. If that's what you want to pass then the problem is with the binary. If you want some help on that problem you could create a new question and show us a bit of the code.

Comment: $PARAM2 is not empty here, but they way the compiled binary takes `-param2` is an empty string. Hope I'm making sense.

For example, `login_binary -user test_user -password ""`

here -password is an empty string to the login_binary.

Comment: @tSpot If you want to pass an empty string then you would do `PARAM2=""; ./binary -param2 "$PARAM2"`.

Comment: `PARAM1="Parameter1"` 
`./sample -param1 $PARAM1 -param2 ""` 
The above line works fine, where as the below lines fail 

`PARAM1="Parameter1"` `PARAM2=\"\"` `./sample -param1 $PARAM1 -param2 $PARAM2`

Comment: @tSpot Use `PARAM1="Parameter1"` `PARAM2=""` `./sample -param1 $PARAM1 -param2 "$PARAM2"`

Comment: Using the code as 

`PARAM1="Parameter1"`
`PARAM2=""`
`./sample -param1 $PARAM1 -param2 "$PARAM2"`

gives the o/p as 

`+ ./sample -param1 Parameter1 -param2 '""'`

Comment: @tSpot Not in my testing. If you ran exactly what I said, `PARAM2=""`, it should work. You  would get  `'""'` if you use `PARAM2='""'` or `PARAM2=\"\"`

Comment: @tSpot If you update your question with the exact script your running I'll be better able to help. Using `PARAM2=""` and `-param2 "$PARAM2"` should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your variable `$PARAM2` is the string `""` (literally two double quotes).

For what you want, I think you just need to initialize it with :

```
PARAM2=""
# Or
PARAM2=''
```

Both are equivalent here.

FYI, the difference between single `'` and double `"` quotes in Bash, is that you can put variable `$foo` in double quotes and they will be evaluated, whereas it will show literal `$` in single quotes :

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo ">$foo<"
>bar<
$ echo '>$foo<'
>$foo<
```

Comment: I already tried with that and the o/p is not what is expected.

`+ ./sample -param1 Parameter1 -param2`

but the expected o/p is
`+ ./sample -param1 Parameter1 -param2 ""`

Comment: You could try `./sample -param1 "$PARAM1" -param2 "$PARAM2"`, it will have the correct output of bash -x, but in your example, it won't change anything (it would be if there were spaces in `$PARAM2`

Comment: Already tried the same. It still gives the o/p as

`+ ./sample -param1 Parameter1 -param2 '""'`

Comment: With both `PARAM2=""` and `./sample -param1 "$PARAM1" -param2 "$PARAM2"`

Comment: I would want the PARAM2 to hold `""` but not an empty string.

That is why I've escaped the double quotes with backslash `\\`

Comment: Oh , I misunderstood you. So, in fact it's already good with your first script. It write ` -param2 '""' ` because it has to escape the double quotes to interpret them as string, and not has text surronding. It is equivalent to write `-param2 \"\"` (but it's not the way bash -x choose to use)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71867/discussion-between-tspot-and-corentin-peuvrel).